# Why the production plan job in to-be-continuous/terraform is launched on a merge request pipeline?

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

I'm wondering why the job "tf-plan-production" in the to-be-continuous/terraform template is the only one running on a merge request pipeline?
Does anybody know the reason behind this?
Because I find it disturbing to have 2 pipelines, 1 detached pipeline containing only a single job while the other pipeline contains all the other jobs (tf-plan-review, tf-tflint, tf-checkov ...). I hesitate to override this rule as I may miss something important.

To be more precise, in this [to-be-continuous template](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/terraform/-/blob/master/templates/gitlab-ci-terraform.yml), all the defined jobs are never run on a merge request pipeline by using the rule :

```
# exclude merge requests
 - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
 when: never
```

Except the "tf-plan-production" job which have the rule:

```
# enabled on merge requests
- if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is this a problem or just an inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`terraform plan` is a nondestructive operation that compares what terraform would create to what exists in output, and creates a diff between existing state and state that has been coded but not created.

Typically it is run when a PR is created so that a dry run is available and visible to the developers, while `terraform apply` is run on merge. If there isn't another environment developers can test their changes in, it is a necessary step.

Comment: My question is really related to the [to-be-continuous template](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/terraform/-/blob/master/templates/gitlab-ci-terraform.yml).  
All the defined jobs don't run in a merge request pipeline by using 
    # exclude merge requests  
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID  
      when: never  
Only the "tf-plan-production" job have the rule:  
    # enabled on merge requests
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

Comment: Well, actually @dan-monego is right: the `terraform plan` job is launched in merge requests to let you see simply **the potential infra changes on prod generated by this MR**. By the way GitLab provides a very nice [Terraform plan diff support](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/mr_integration.html) in merge requests that is off-course implemented in the `to-be-continuous`template :)